# problems encountered when using gpuimage

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm used to construct 1 gpuimage imaging applications. But I'm having some problems.
The first is when I select the front camera and back camera. After a few clicks on the button, my application will crash.
The next problem is my camera images show elongated. And after the camera was in the opposite direction.
Who can help me solve this problem?
Thank you

```
- (void)viewDidLoad     {
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    iFlash = 1;
    hasBlur = NO;
    cropFilter = [[GPUImageCropFilter alloc] initWithCropRegion:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.75f)];
    filter = [[GPUImageRGBFilter alloc] init];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        [self setUpCamera];
    });

    //cropFilter = [[GPUImageCropFilter alloc] initWithCropRegion:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.75f)];
    filter = [[GPUImageRGBFilter alloc] init];

    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; 
}

- (IBAction)rotateCameraPressed:(id)sender {
    hasBlur = NO;

    if(sttRotate == 0) {
        sttRotate = 1;
        [self removeAllTargets];
        [self setUpCamera];
    }
    else if(sttRotate == 1){
        [self removeAllTargets];        
        sttRotate = 0;
        [self setUpCamera];
    }
}

- (void)setUpCamera { 
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    // Has camera

        if(sttRotate == 1) { 
            stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront];
        }
        else if(sttRotate == 0) {           
            stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
        }

        stillCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
        runOnMainQueueWithoutDeadlocking(^{
            [stillCamera startCameraCapture];
            if([stillCamera.inputCamera hasFlash]){
                [self.flashToggleButton setEnabled:NO];
                [stillCamera.inputCamera lockForConfiguration:nil];
                if([stillCamera.inputCamera flashMode] == AVCaptureFlashModeOff){
                    [self.flashToggleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flash-off"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
                else if ([stillCamera.inputCamera flashMode] == AVCaptureFlashModeAuto){
                   [self.flashToggleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flash-auto"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
                else {
                [self.flashToggleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flash"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
                [stillCamera.inputCamera unlockForConfiguration];
                [self.flashToggleButton setEnabled:YES];
            }
            else {
                [self.flashToggleButton setEnabled:NO];
            }
            [self prepareFilter];
        });
    }
    else {
        // No camera 
        runOnMainQueueWithoutDeadlocking(^{
            [self prepareFilter];
        });
    }
}
```